# Copy Image to Local Folder Using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

How can we copy image from source to local folder using python selenium process.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.python.org/')

# get the image source
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@class="python-logo"]')
src = img.get_attribute('src')

# download the image
urllib.urlretrieve(src, "python-logo.png")

driver.close()
```